# How can I use the share icon in android

Tags: android, layout, menu, share

I'm sure this is a duplicate question - but I can't seem to find a fix online.

I'm trying to add a share button to my app. But at the moment I've got the issue where instead of the share icon (the weird USB/tree/node thing) - I've got the 3 dots associated with the overflow menu - that when pressed, open a popup option - which contains an item called share.

I have the correct functionality - but how can I use the icon, rather than the menu + popup nonsense.

Thank you -

Ollie

P.S. android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share" is a completely valid path - so it's not that

---

QuestionActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Share Icon Functionality
        case R.id.menu_item_share : Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Help me, I'm stuck on a game!");
                                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareTextFormatter());
                                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                                    break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

menu_question.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.home.ditloids.QuestionActivity">

    <item
        android:id = "@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction = "ifRoom"
        android:title = "Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:actionProviderClass = "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Comment: What class does your activity inherit from?

Comment: QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xmlns:app namespace is wrong, it's missing a "http://".

This leads to app:showAsAction being ignored.

Comment: You're a wizard. I would have never realised that - not sure how it happened, but whatever! Thank you, thank you, thank you! :) Have a great day/night

Answer (score 0):

In **menu_question.xml** , try changing `showAsAction` to:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.home.ditloids.QuestionActivity">

<item
    android:id = "@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction = "always"
    android:title = "Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:actionProviderClass = "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Comment: I've played around with that before - and I just tried it again - no dice :( Thank you though :)